# How to select a button after page has fully loaded?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

Using python and selenium, When I click on a continue button `'continue_pax'`, the page that loads up is the exact same page as before, so I use `pax_page` again to wait for the element to load up and then click on the `'continue_pax'` again. However, my browser crashes when I do this. I think it maybe because it is trying to click the 'continue' button too fast.

I do get an error stating:

```
, line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (834.5, 562). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-outer"></div>
```

How can I click on the continue button again after page has reloaded to move onto the `seats_page` element?

```
pax_page = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl08_butAddBagsForAll")))

... filling for code in between

    #continue to seats
    continue_pax = driver.find_element_by_id("pageContinue").click()
    pax_page
    continue_pax
    seats_page = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "findyourseat")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a modal "popup" covering the button - I suspect *the loading spinner*.

Two things to try:

- wait for the `Continue` button *to be clickable*:

  ```
  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pageContinue"))).click();
  ```
- wait for the *invisibility of the modal*:

  ```
  wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "modal-outer")))
  ```

Comment: Thanks again python legend :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303663/how-to-loop-through-and-click-on-relevant-items - Virtually this is last issue I have and I'm finished really. Feel free to have a look