# How to loop through and click on relevant items

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below I have four radio buttons that each select a passenger.

```
<input checked="checked" name="passenger" id="passenger-0" data-passengerindex="0" type="radio">
    <input checked="checked" name="passenger" id="passenger-1" data-passengerindex="1" type="radio">
    <input checked="checked" name="passenger" id="passenger-2" data-passengerindex="2" type="radio">
    <input checked="checked" name="passenger" id="passenger-3" data-passengerindex="3" type="radio">
```

Below is a block of code that shows a row of seats (in row 6), some infants seats `(class="seat  infant")` and the others normal seats (normal seats are seats noinfant - `class="seat  noinfant"` and seats `class="seat"`.

```
    <td>
        <a href="#6A" title="Seat Suitable for Infants 6A" data-seat="6A" data-seatid="81374518" data-seatgroup="0" class="seat  infant" data-personid="" data-infantseat="True">
            <span>Seat Suitable for Infants 6A</span>
        </a>
    </td><td>
        <a href="#6B" title="Seat Suitable for Infants 6B" data-seat="6B" data-seatid="81374519" data-seatgroup="0" class="seat  infant" data-personid="" data-infantseat="True">
            <span>Seat Suitable for Infants 6B</span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#6C" title="Seat Suitable for Infants 6C" data-seat="6C" data-seatid="81374520" data-seatgroup="0" class="seat  infant" data-personid="" data-infantseat="True">
            <span>Seat Suitable for Infants 6C</span>
        </a>
    </td>
        <td class="aisle">6</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#6D" title="Seat Suitable for Infants 6D" data-seat="6D" data-seatid="81374522" data-seatgroup="1" class="seat  noinfant" data-personid="" data-infantseat="True">
            <span>Seat Suitable for Infants 6D</span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#6E" title="Seat Suitable for Infants 6E" data-seat="6E" data-seatid="81374523" data-seatgroup="1" class="seat" data-personid="" data-infantseat="True">
            <span>Seat Suitable for Infants 6E</span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#6F" title="Seat Suitable for Infants 6F" data-seat="6F" data-seatid="81374524" data-seatgroup="1" class="seat  infant" data-personid="" data-infantseat="True">
            <span>Seat Suitable for Infants 6F</span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When a seat is selected, the below happens:

- Class changes from `class="seat  infant"` to `class="seat  infant reserved selected` for infant seats
- Normal Seats - `class="seat  noinfant"` to `class="seat  noinfant reserved selected` OR `class="seat"` to `class="seat reserved selected`

Below is what I need help implementing:

Starting from Row 1 and continuing along

- For the first two passengers, click the next available **infant
  seats** (one passenger per infant seat)
- For the last two passengers, click any seat starting from row 1
  onwards

We don't need to actually select a passenger as they get selected automatically after selecting a seat, and first passenger is already selected when page is loaded.

Does anybody as I have only used Python for 4 days so no way near advanced know how to implement the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea would be:

- depending on whether a passenger has an infant or not (the `data-hasinfant` attribute), decide which seat to pick
- use CSS class selectors with `not()` to get to the non-selected and non-reserved seats

Sample implementation:

```
for passenger in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ol.passengerlist li[data-personid]"):
    passenger.click()

    has_infant = passenger.get_attribute("data-hasinfant")

    # choose seats
    if has_infant:
        # select a non-selected infant seat
        seat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".planebody a.seat.infant:not(.reserved):not(.selected)")
    else:
        # select a non-reserved non-selected seat
        seat = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".planebody a.seat:not(.reserved):not(.selected)")

    print("Passenger: %s, choosing seat: %s" % (passenger.text.strip(), seat.get_attribute("data-seat")))
    seat.click()
```